# How to generate open bible image in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anybody help me how to achive this type of image using only latex coding?[image]

Comment: First, you have to prepare the text in "plain" form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very, very simple version w/o the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\openbook}[1][black]
   {\begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[#1] (-0.4,0) rectangle (0.4,0.6) (180:0.03cm) arc (180:360:0.03cm);
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
       \draw[line width=0.02cm,#1,fill=white,miter limit=1]
          (0,0.03) to[controls={+(150:0.15cm) and +(25:0.15cm)}] (-0.36,0.04) --
          (-0.36,0.64) to[controls={+(25:0.15cm) and +(150:0.15cm)}]
          (0,0.6) to[controls={+(30:0.15cm) and +(155:0.15cm)}] (0.36,0.64) --
          (0.36,0.04) to[controls={+(155:0.15cm) and +(30:0.15cm)}]
          (0,0.03) -- (0,0.6);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
 \openbook[red]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to run your code Mr. Jurgen?

Comment: I agree that there's no MWE by the O.P. but please, wrap a document around this...

Comment: Yes, of course, it wasn't deliberately, just a lack of time.