# How to Bend Words to the Arching Pages of an Open Book Image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Consider the following image of an open book which I modified a little from the answer posted on [How to generate open bible image in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361022/how-to-generate-open-bible-image-in-latex) ---

[image]

The image was generated by the Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\openbook}[1][black]
   {\begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[#1] (-0.4,0) rectangle (0.4,0.6) (180:0.03cm) arc (180:360:0.03cm);
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
       \draw[line width=0.02cm,#1,fill=white,miter limit=1]
          (0,0.03) to[controls={+(150:0.15cm) and +(25:0.15cm)}] (-0.36,0.04) --
          (-0.36,0.64) to[controls={+(25:0.15cm) and +(150:0.15cm)}]
          (0,0.6) to[controls={+(30:0.15cm) and +(155:0.15cm)}] (0.36,0.64) --
          (0.36,0.04) to[controls={+(155:0.15cm) and +(30:0.15cm)}]
          (0,0.03) -- (0,0.6);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

 \scalebox{15}{\openbook[brown]}
\Large

\vspace*{-245pt}\hskip 30pt \begin{minipage}{1.75in}
Here are words. 

\vskip 10pt

\hskip 12pt I would like to be able to add even more words---so that they appear as a natural part of this open book illustration.

\vskip 10pt

\hskip 12pt Thank you.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

QUESTION: Can anyone show me how I may include some words on the image so that they ``arch'' in a natural way on the pages displayed? Also, I don't know if I have included the words I have posted on the image in the most expedient way (using *minipage* in conjunction with *vspace* and *hskip*)---any suggestions as to improvement on that end is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You may find this easier to write the whole thing as a rectangular flat plane and then use a graphical photo editor to add the distortion, then include back into the document as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something similar to what you like with a TikZ text decoration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=2em},
        text={|\Large|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[brown] (-6,0) rectangle (6,9) (180:0.45cm) arc (180:360:0.45cm);
  \draw[line width=0.3cm,brown,fill=white,miter limit=1]
      (0,0.45) to[controls={+(150:2.25cm) and +(25:2.25cm)}] (-5.4,0.6) --
      (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}]
      (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6) --
      (5.4,0.6) to[controls={+(155:2.25cm) and +(30:2.25cm)}]
      (0,0.45) -- (0,9);
% Left page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{Here are the words}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-2\baselineskip}{This is not perfect}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-4\baselineskip}{but it could be}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-6\baselineskip}{an approximation}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-8\baselineskip}{of what you like.}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
% Right page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{You can write also}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-2\baselineskip}{on the right page,}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-4\baselineskip}{of course!}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this answer.

Comment: @mlchristians You're welcome, and thank you for accepting it.