# Blotting Out the Curve Used to Bend Text in a Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, text-decorations, text-manipulation, tikz-pic

This is a follow-up to a question I posted yesterday:

[How to Bend Words to Conform to the Arching Pages of an Open Book Image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583652/how-to-bend-words-to-conform-to-the-arching-pages-of-an-open-book-image)

After receiving no answer to the above question, I have since been able to bend a sentence and place it in the open book image. (It may not be an optimal approach, but it's a start---if someone can offer a better alternative, I would appreciate it.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\openbook}[1][black]
   {\begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[#1] (-0.4,0) rectangle (0.4,0.6) (180:0.03cm) arc (180:360:0.03cm);
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
       \draw[line width=0.02cm,#1,fill=white,miter limit=1]
          (0,0.03) to[controls={+(150:0.15cm) and +(25:0.15cm)}] (-0.36,0.04) --
          (-0.36,0.64) to[controls={+(25:0.15cm) and +(150:0.15cm)}]
          (0,0.6) to[controls={+(30:0.15cm) and +(155:0.15cm)}] (0.36,0.64) --
          (0.36,0.04) to[controls={+(155:0.15cm) and +(30:0.15cm)}]
          (0,0.03) -- (0,0.6);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

 \scalebox{15}{\openbook[brown]}
\large

\vskip -255pt
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (One) at (-1,1) {}; %[shape=circle,draw] {$One$}; 
\node (Two) at (5,0) {}; %[shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};

\draw[white] [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|Bending some words.}}}]      (One) to [bend left=65] (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

However, I have not been able to make the underlying curve entirely disappear (as you can see). I tried coloring it white, but it runs into the brown portion of the image---making it conspicuous.

QUESTION: Is there a way I can blot out the underlying curve completely?

Thank you.

Comment: Using `\path` instead of `\draw` should do it.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey Thank you very much. \path{} does exactly what I want.

Comment: I started writing a short answer on that, but tried the code and made a few changes to it in addition and put that in the answer as well. Hope that's okay!

Comment: @Andrew Stacey Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use a path in some fashion but don't want the actual path to be drawn then the way to achieve this is usually to define the path using `\path` rather than `\draw`.  In addition, if all you want to do is decorate the path then you can use the decoration on the path directly and not via a postaction.

Looking at the rest of the code, I'd also implement the book as a `pic` so that you can embed it in the picture directly and don't have to shuffle boxes around.  I'd also make the decorated path a copy of the edge path exactly - it makes it look a bit more coordinated.

I've also adjusted the coordinates so that the scale factor of 15 is in place.  This may not have been necessary, but at one point in messing around in it then the scaling was interfering with the text adjustments.

The loop for iterating through the text is a bit low-level, but I don't know if the `\foreach` loops can work on a "do until" paradigm rather than looping through a specific list.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583881/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\unpacklipsum[8]
\let\textToTypeset\lipsumexp

\newcount\bookline

\tikzset{
  open book colour/.initial=brown,
  open book/.pic={
    \fill[
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/open book colour}
    ]
    (-6,0) rectangle (6,9) (180:0.45cm) arc (180:360:0.45cm);
    \draw[
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/open book colour},
      fill=white,
    ]
    (0,0.45) to[controls={+(150:2.25cm) and +(25:2.25cm)}] (-5.4,0.6) --
    (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}]
    (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6) --
    (5.4,0.6) to[controls={+(155:2.25cm) and +(30:2.25cm)}]
    (0,0.45) -- (0,9);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[line width=1mm] {open book};

\bookline=5\relax
\loop\unless\ifx\textToTypeset\empty\relax
\path[
  decorate,
  decoration={
    text along path,
    text align=left,
    text align/left indent=1ex,
    text align/right indent=1ex,
    text={|\sffamily|\textToTypeset}
  },
  yshift=-\the\bookline em
]
(-5.4,9.6) .. controls +(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm) .. (0,9);
\let\textToTypeset=\pgfdecorationrestoftext
\advance\bookline by 1\relax
\repeat

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Book with text on lines]

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer.